# Strange SQLite behavior: Not returning results on simple queries

Tags: sqlite

Ok, so I have a basic table called "ledger", it contains fields of various types, integers, varchar, etc.

In my program, I used to use a query with no "from" predicate to collect all of the rows, which of course works fine.  But... I changed my code to allow selecting one row at a time using "where acctno = x" (where X is the account number I want to select at the time).

I thought this must be a bug in the client library for my programming language, so I tested it in the SQLite command-line client - and it still doesn't work!

I am relatively new to SQLite, but I have been using Oracle, MS SQL Server, etc. for years and never seen this type of issue before.

Other things I can tell you:
* Queries using other integer fields also don't work
* Queries on char fields work
* Querying it as a string (with the account number on quotes) still doesn't work.  (I thought maybe the numbers were stored as a string inadvertently).
* Accessing rows by rowid works fine - which is why I can edit the database with GUI tools with no noticeable problem.

Examples:

Query with no WHERE (works fine):

```
1|0|0|JPY|8|Paid-In Capital|C|X|0|X|0|0||||0|0|0|
0|0|0|JPY|11|Root Account|P|X|0|X|0|0|SYSTEM|20121209|150000|0|0|0|
3|0|0|JPY|13|Mitsubishi Bank Futsuu|A|X|0|X|0|0|SYSTEM|20121209|150000|0|0|0|
4|0|0|JPY|14|Japan Post Bank|A|X|0|X|0|0|SYSTEM|20121209|150000|0|0|0|
...
```

Query with WHERE clause: (no results)

```
sqlite> select * from ledger where acctno=1;                                    
sqlite>
```

putting quotes around the 1 above changes nothing.

Interestingly enough, "select * from ledger where acctno > 1" returns results!  However since it returns ALL results, it's not terrible useful.

I'm sure someone will ask about the table structure, so here goes:

```
sqlite> .schema ledger
CREATE TABLE "LEDGER" (
 "ACCTNO" integer(10,0) NOT NULL,
 "drbal" integer(20,0) NOT NULL,
 "crbal" integer(20,0) NOT NULL,
 "CURRKEY" char(3,0) NOT NULL,
 "TEXTKEY" integer(10,0),
 "TEXT" VARCHAR(64,0),
 "ACCTYPECD" CHAR(1,0) NOT NULL,
 "ACCSTCD" CHAR(1,0),
 "PACCTNO" number(10,0) NOT NULL,
 "CATCD" number(10,0),
 "TRANSNO" number(10,0) NOT NULL,
 "extrefno" number(10,0),
 "UPDATEUSER" VARCHAR(32,0),
 "UPDATEDATE" text(8,0),
 "UPDATETIME" TEXT(6,0),
 "PAYEECD" number(10,0) NOT NULL,
 "drbal2" number(10,0) NOT NULL,
 "crbal2" number(10,0) NOT NULL,
 "delind" boolean,
PRIMARY KEY("ACCTNO"),
CONSTRAINT "fk_curr" FOREIGN KEY ("CURRKEY") REFERENCES "CURRENCY" ("CUR
RKEY") ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

The strangest thing is that I have other similar tables where this works fine!

```
sqlite> select * from journalhdr where transno=13;
13|Test transaction ATM Withdrawel 20130213|20130223||20130223||
```

TransNo in that table is also integer (10,0) NOT NULL - this is what makes me thing it is something to do with the values.

Another clue is that the sort order seems to be based on ascii, not numeric:

```
sqlite> select * from ledger order by acctno;
0|0|0|JPY|11|Root Account|P|X|0|X|0|0|SYSTEM|20121209|150000|0|0|0|
1|0|0|JPY|8|Paid-In Capital|C|X|0|X|0|0||||0|0|0|
10|0|0|USD|20|Sallie Mae|L|X|0|X|0|0|SYSTEM|20121209|153900|0|0|0|
21|0|0|USD|21|Skrill|A|X|0|X|0|0|SYSTEM|20121209|154000|0|0|0|
22|0|0|USD|22|AES|L|X|0|X|0|0|SYSTEM|20121209|154200|0|0|0|
23|0|0|JPY|23|Marui|L|X|0|X|0|0|SYSTEM|20121209|154400|0|0|0|
24|0|0|JPY|24|Amex JP|L|X|0|X|0|0|SYSTEM|20121209|154500|0|0|0|
3|0|0|JPY|13|Mitsubishi Bank Futsuu|A|X|0|X|0|0|SYSTEM|20121209|150000|0|0|0|
```

Of course the sort order on journalhdr (where the select works properly) is numeric.

Solved! (sort-of)
The data can be fixed like this:

sqlite> update ledger set acctno = 23 where rowid = 13; 
sqlite> select * from ledger where acctno = 25;                                 
25|0|0|JPY|0|Test|L|X|0|X|0|0|SYSTEM|20130224|132500|0|0|0|

Still, if it was stored as strings, then that leave a few questions:
1. Why couldn't I select it as a string using the quotes?
2. How did it get stored as a string since it is a valid integer?
3. How would you go about detecting this problem normally besides noticing bizzarre symptoms?

Although the data would normally be entered by my program, some of it was created by hand using Navicat, so I assume the problem must lie there.

Comment: Due to SQLite's [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), it should not be possible to have strings that look like a number in an `integer` column.

Comment: @CL.: but it is possible - and my example demonstrates it.

Comment: Actually, I suppose it was the type affinity that *allowed* it to happen.  If there were a strict type option, then the values either would be converted to numeric, or not imported at all.  Anyway, now I know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are victim of SQLite [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Even though SQLite defines system of [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), which sets some rules on how input strings or numbers will be converted to actual internal values, but it does NOT prevent software that is using prepared statements to explicitly set any type (and data value) for the column (and this can be different per row!).

This can be shown by this simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE ledger (acctno INTEGER, name VARCHAR(16));
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES(1,          'John'); -- INTEGER '1'
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES(2 || X'00', 'Zack'); -- BLOB    '2\0'
```

I have inserted second row not as INTEGER, but as binary string containing *embedded zero byte*. This reproduces your issue exactly, see this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/10fc5/3), step by step. You can also execute these commands in `sqlite3`, you will get the same result.

## Below is Perl script that also reproduces this issue

This script creates just 2 rows with `acctno` having values of integer `1` for first, and `"2\0"` for second row. `"2\0"` means string consisting of 2 bytes: first is digit `2`, and second is `0` (zero) byte.

Of course, it is very difficult to visually tell `"2\0"` from just `"2"`, but this is what script below demonstrates:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI qw(:sql_types);
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:test.db") or die DBI::errstr();
$dbh->do("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ledger");
$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE ledger (acctno INTEGER, name VARCHAR(16))");
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO ledger (acctno, name) VALUES (?, ?)");
$sth->bind_param(1, "1", SQL_INTEGER);
$sth->bind_param(2, "John");
$sth->execute();
$sth->bind_param(1, "2\0", SQL_BLOB);
$sth->bind_param(2, "Zack");
$sth->execute();
$sth = $dbh->prepare(
    "SELECT count(*) FROM ledger WHERE acctno = ?");
$sth->bind_param(1, "1");
$sth->execute();
my ($num1) = $sth->fetchrow_array();
print "Number of rows matching id '1' is $num1\n";
$sth->bind_param(1, "2");
$sth->execute();
my ($num2) = $sth->fetchrow_array();
print "Number of rows matching id '2' is $num2\n";
$sth->bind_param(1, "2\0", SQL_BLOB);
$sth->execute();
my ($num3) = $sth->fetchrow_array();
print "Number of rows matching id '2<0>' is $num3\n";
```

Output of this script is:

```
Number of rows matching id '1' is 1
Number of rows matching id '2' is 0
Number of rows matching id '2<0>' is 1
```

If you were to look at resultant table using any SQLite tool (including `sqlite3`), it will print `2` for second row - they all get confused by trailing 0 inside a BLOB when it gets coerced to string or number.

Note that I had to use custom param binding to coerce type to BLOB and permit null bytes stored:

```
 $sth->bind_param(1, "2\0", SQL_BLOB);
```

Long story short, it is either some of your client programs, or some of client tools like Navicat which screwed it up.

Comment: I have added easier way to reproduce it and [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/10fc5/3) that demonstrates it clearly

Comment: I am almost certain it was the outdated version of Navicat.  I love Navicat, but older versions for OS X are a bit buggy.  The frustration with this bug wasn't that it happened, but that it was so difficult to figure out.  Once you know the issue, it's not that difficult to fix.  (For example, dump and re-load the table, etc).  If you have Foreign Keys, though, you are in for a nightmare.